# NLP clock Bot - How to properly extract information from text input using NLTK and run certain functions?

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk, bots

I am trying to build a bot in python using NLTK (natural language toolkit) that can tell the time when a user inputs the question: *What time it is?*

I came up with the following two solutions (I am not sure if it is the right approach, there are not so many examples/docs that could help me to wrap my head around NLTK)

In the first approach I check for the word "time" in the question, if its there I display the current time:

```
sent_tokenized = word_tokenize('What time it is?')

train_sents = []
file = ["What/WP time/NN it/PRP is/VBZ ?/."]
for line in file:
    train_sents.append([nltk.tag.str2tuple(t) for t in line.split()])


unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(train_sents)
tagged_sentence = unigram_tagger.tag(sent_tokenized)

for token in tagged_sentence:
    if token[0] == "time" and token[1] == "NN":
        print "The time is: " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
```

The second would be to tag the word "time" with a custom tag like "INTENT", and train the above `unigram_tagger`, so when the tag "INTENT" is encountered inside the loop, the bot would again display the time:

```
train_sent = "What/WP time/INTENT it/PRP is/VBZ ?/."
```

Is any of these approaches pointing in the right direction, or how could I do this in the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Why "What time it is?" instead of "What time is it?"?

Comment: @Tagc its just a  typo

Comment: What I mean is, do you want your bot to respond to users asking "What time is it?" (expected), "What time it is?" (odd) or both?

Comment: So, what's your question? Your code runs fine on my machine... This seems primarily opinion-based if you're asking, "Am I doing this right?"

Comment: It works, but say I have 20 functions: tellTime (), playMusic(), turnOnLights () etc., if using the above method (the first) and I keep writing if statements things will get kinda messy. What I would like to know is, how to handle this problem the way pros do.